# Laravel 5.6 routes locale

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change locale in my route but locale is always set to 'en'

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'fr'], function (){
    App::setLocale('fr');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function (){
    App::setLocale('en');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

fr/home getLocale return 'en' 
en/home getLocale return 'en'

```
Route::prefix('fr')->group(function () {
    App::setLocale('fr');
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
});

Route::prefix('en')->group(function () {
    App::setLocale('en');
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Have same issue

Comment: Unclear, Plz give me briefly describtion.

Comment: App::setLocale should be placed in Controller. Not the router

Comment: I guess this is because both of these group functions are called in sequence, so the latter always overwrites the previous locale value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define locale in the `Group` method. It just will cause the last locale will apply.

Instead you can follow [original guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization) and implement routing for each method like the docs said:

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

Or create group with [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) that will define right language.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use standard format from documentation?

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
    // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes

One other thing to notice is to check your NGINX conf file or if apache .htaccess file. They can do unwanted redirects.

Comment: Can I see your route's file. Should be pretty basic. One other thing with url's is to check your NGINX conf file or if apache .htaccess file.